# Intitializing the Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to install the Kubernetes cluster on ubuntu 18.04 system..

As part of intializing the cluster with below command getting below error

```
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.14.0: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: remote error: tls: access denied
, error: exit status 1
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.14.0: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: remote error: tls: access denied
, error: exit status 1
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.14.0: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: remote error: tls: access denied
, error: exit status 1
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.14.0: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: remote error: tls: access denied
, error: exit status 1
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: remote error: tls: access denied
, error: exit status 1
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.3.10: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: remote error: tls: access denied
, error: exit status 1
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.3.1: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: remote error: tls: access denied
, error: exit status 1
```

When i tried to run `wget https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/` i am getting below error:

```
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Username/Password Authentication Failed.
```

Can you please let me know what is the issue.

Comment: Which command are you trying to run initially?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have

```
[root@instance-1 ~]# wget https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/
--2019-08-26 12:58:24--  https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/
Resolving k8s.gcr.io (k8s.gcr.io)... 64.233.167.82, 2a00:1450:400c:c06::52
Connecting to k8s.gcr.io (k8s.gcr.io)|64.233.167.82|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authorization failed.
```

That can be the proxy issue. Inspect  [[Kubeadm] Failing to pull images](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1201), and more concrete [this answer](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1201#issuecomment-494686022.

So try to [configure your docker to use proxy](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-configure-docker-to-use-proxy/) and I hope your issue would be resolved.

And below is summarized set of commands for both the methods:

Method 1 : Configuring proxy variables in the /etc/sysconfig/docker file

-Add following configuration in /etc/sysconfig/docker file

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/docker
HTTP_PROXY="http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@[your.proxy.server]:[port]"
HTTPS_PROXY="https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@[your.proxy.server]:[port]
```

-Restart docker

```
# service docker restart
```

Method 2:

1) Create a drop-in

```
# mkdir /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
```

2) Create a file with name `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf` that adds the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://user01:password@10.10.10.10:8080/"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://user01:password@10.10.10.10:8080/"
Environment="NO_PROXY= hostname.example.com,172.10.10.10"
```

3) reload the systemd daemon

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
```

4) restart docker

`# systemctl restart dock`er
5) Verify that the configuration has been loaded:

```
# systemctl show docker --property Environment
Environment=GOTRACEBACK=crash HTTP_PROXY=http://10.10.10.10:8080/ HTTPS_PROXY=http://10.10.10.10:8080/ NO_PROXY= hostname.example.com,172.10.10.10
```